# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady and import models

Tags: python, django, django-models

My django project structure is like below.

```
watcher 
    |-config    
        |-__init__.py
        |- asgi.py
        |- config.ini
        |- settings.py
        |- urls.py
        |- wsgi.py
    |-tower
        |-__init__.py
        |-admin.py
        |-apps.py
        |-models.py
        |-tests.py
        |-views.py
    |-manage.py
```

My apps.py code is like below.

```
    # import os
    # os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "watcher.settings")
    # import django
    # django.setup()
    from .models import CryptoTicker, CryptoTrade, CryptoOrderbookMain, CryptoOrderbookSub
    
    
    class TowerConfig(AppConfig):
        default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
        name = 'tower'
    
        def ready(self):
            print("Hello")
            socket = SocketClient()
            socket.start()
    
    class SocketClient(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.url = "wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1"
    
    
            self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
                url=self.url,
                header=headers,
                on_message=self.on_message,
                on_error=self.on_error,
                on_close=self.on_close,
                on_open=self.on_open
            )
    
            self.step = 0
    
        def run(self):
            while True:
                self.ws.run_forever()
    
        def on_message(self, ws, message):
            data = message.decode('utf-8')
            self.process(data)
            if self.step < 0:
                print("----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----")
                print()
                print(data)
                print()
                print("----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----")
                self.step += 1
    
        def on_error(self, ws, err):
            print(err)

        def on_close(self, ws, status_code, msg):
            print("closed!")
    
        def on_open(self, ws):
            print("connected!")
            ws.send('[{"ticket":"siren1"}, {"type":"ticker","codes":["KRW-BTC", "KRW-SOL"]}, {"type":"trade","codes":["KRW-BTC", "KRW-SOL"]}, {"type":"orderbook","codes":["KRW-BTC", "KRW-SOL"]}, {"format": "DEFAULT"}]')
    
        def process(self, data):
            pass
```

After running 'python manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:8000', I got below errors.

```
      File "D:\git\crypto-siren\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My suspicion is that importing models make errors.
(from .models import CryptoTicker, CryptoTrade, CryptoOrderbookMain, CryptoOrderbookSub)
Could you give me some advice?
Thank you.

I tried adding below

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "watcher.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

but, I got another errors like below.

```
  File "D:\git\crypto-siren\watcher\tower\apps.py", line 15, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "D:\git\crypto-siren\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\git\crypto-siren\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 83, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Another solution: we success to use websocket by fastapi while the main api server was using django.